# How to use C-Library in C#

Tags: c#, c, .a

i´ve downloaded a BACnet-Stack from http://sourceforge.net/projects/bacnet/ but it is written in c and i want to use it in c#.

I´ve been reading for 4 hours now about how to get it done but i´m not any further. Most answers are to write the code anew in c# but i have no clue of c . I opened a workspace in Code::Blocks to look into the code and compiled a library into a a.-file. But how can i use it?

Greetings,

Stefan

Comment: There appears to be a C# version of BACnet Stack - http://bacsharp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Check this qsns ans I think it is useful for you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: @jmk the site and files were edited last in feb-2008...i dont think theire accurate anymore

Comment: @typ1804 The last update to the code is September 2012 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/bacsharp/

Comment: what is your toolchain? Visual studio on Windows / Cygwin on Windows / Mono on linux, etc?

Comment: i use visual studio express c# in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address alike situation, Microsoft provides attributes, assembly, and marshaling to offer interoperability between managed-unmanaged code(not .net aware/running outside the clr boundaries) and managed-legacy COM. 
Investigate the use of dynamics and the (Dynamic language runtime- DLR) which should be more than fine. 
code example (using kernel32.dll) as an example of calling unmanaged code from a managed context

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="MoveFile",
ExactSpelling=false, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode,
SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool MoveFile(string sourceFile, string destinationFile);

//calling the function
static void Main()
{
    MoveFile("sheet.xls", @"c:\sheet.xls");
}
```

check this pdf also: http://www.nag.com/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_Sharp.pdf

Comment: -1: Only "marshaling" is at all relevant to the OP, and even that's not really useful content.

Comment: But how can i convert a a.-file into a .dll?