# Can I import libxml2 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, libxml2

I am creating a custom SOAP parser for a C# project.

I would like to import libxml2 (a pure c library) to my project. Is this doable?

Are there any C# alternatives in .NET? Is there a C# port of libxml2?

Comment: [Use a C library from C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have probably allready solved this but i will add this:

I was looking for the same thing and found out there is a nuGet package for [libxml2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libxml2/)

you might find this helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use standard `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader` from `System.Xml` namespace which internally use Microsoft Xml Parser which is pretty fast. You can even use DOM oriented acces with `System.Xml.XmlDocument` or `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`. Even there is `System.Runtime.Remoting.SoapServices` class which help you with soap message.

If you want to consume some SOAP web service, than you can easily import it and visual studio will create strong typed object for you for free without any touch to the SOAP message. You can refer to: [MSDN Consuming Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561062.aspx)