# How to access c objects in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c

I am basically .net developer and having zero knowledge on c. Today i got below task. There is a c program to add two numbers. C program contains method which takes two numbers to add as parameters. Now I want to access these c methods(objects) in my .net MVC or webapi2. I should call c program(object) to add two numbers and should give output in HTML using .net. I have no idea where to start this! Can someone educate me on this or someone share me usefull links to in order to understand in better way. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is COM (component object model). Or it might be Windows Communication Foundation. Or they might be asking for a simple `exec` type thing

Comment: Two suggestions: narrow your question down, and show a little bit of research effort. First issue I believe is: how do you [call a C library from C#?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=call+c+library+from+c%23&oq=call+c+library+from+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.9680j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) What have you tried?  What is not working?  Show us some code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and feedback. I have not tried anything. By looking above comments I understood there are two ways to do this. First one is com second one is as you said call c library from c#. So these both ways works?

Comment: What format is the "C program" or "c methods (objects)"?  Is it an executable, or are you calling a library (I assumed library, but perhaps I'm wrong)?  If you need to call an executable, [have a look at](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) `Process.Start()` with parameters.  There are a few different ways to call things outside of managed code, but it largely depends on what you are trying to call.  Need more info.

Comment: Thanks pcdev. Let's say c library I want to access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a C library from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093292/use-a-c-library-from-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Simplest method is to use P/Invoke and DllImport in C# to call the C methods. Your question does not make sense - C is not an OOP language, nor does it support objects. C++ added OOP to C